# Rendering React component inside Template Literals using Ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am updating `innerHTML` using `Ref` attribute in react. I have a component called as `<Spinner>` which I would like to insert in the `div` element as shown below :

```js
const Drop = () => {

    const loadRef = useRef();

    const loadFiles = () => {
        loadRef.current.innerHTML = `<Spinner name="circle" />`
        // ... other actions 
    }

    return (
        <div ref={loadRef}></div>
    )
}
```

How can I do this?

.

Answer (score 2):

Using `innerHTML` will not render that content as React component, it will be rendered as text i recommend to use conditional rendering based on some state or prop :

```
const Drop = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const loadFiles = () => {
        setLoading(true);
       
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {loading && <Spinner name="circle" /> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

or a prop

```
const Drop = ({loading,setLoading}) => {
    
    const loadFiles = () => {
        setLoading(true);
       
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {loading && <Spinner name="circle" /> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.innerHTML` - put the `Spinner` inside `Drop`'s returned JSX:

```
const Drop = () => {
    const [showingSpinner, setShowingSpinner] = useState(false);
    const loadFiles = () => {
        setShowingSpinner(true);
        // ... other actions 
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {showingSpinner ? <Spinner name="circle" /> : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need inner Html for this. You can try this

```
import React,{useState } from 'react';
import Spinner from 'Your Spinner'; // Your Spinner Module

function App() {
  
  const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);
  
  const showSpinner = () => {
    
    setSpinner(true);
    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => showSpinner()}>Show Spinner</button>
     
       // Tenary Operation
       {spinner ? <Spinner name="circle" /> : null}
    </div>
  )
}




export default App;
```